# Assist in debugging this simple javascript split function

Tags: javascript, split

I am trying to write a loop to check whether a card number has the right format but I can not get it to work and debugging is just not working.

I need to check for the format: XXX-XXX-XXX1

Here is my javascript:

```
if(pieces[2] == ''){
                $('#hcc_validated').value = 'incorrect';
                showCardError();
                $('#fname').value = '3';
            }else if((pieces[0].length == 3 && typeof pieces[0] == "string") && (pieces[1].length == 3 && typeof pieces[1] == "string") && (thirdp.length == 3 && typeof thirdp == "string") && (fourthp.length == 1 && typeof fourthp == "number")){
                $('#hcc_validated').value = 'validated';
                showCardError();
                $('#fname').value = '2';
            }else{
                $('#hcc_validated').value = 'not validated';
                showCardError();
                $('#fname').value = '1';
            }
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? (This is just part of the code but I know for sure that this is where I am going wrong as the rest of the code works fine...

Here is my JSFiddle if you want full code:
[JSFIddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fYQxg/)

Thanks guys

Comment: Did you try using Regex? [see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html)

Comment: Define "can not get it to work". What is the expected outcome? What is the actual outcome? Are there any error messages?

Comment: You probably need to use `$(...).val('not validated');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be better solved using regular expressions.

Specifically;

```
[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}1
```

Javascript:

```
var inputstring = "123-123-1231";
var pattern = new RegExp("[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}1");
var result = pattern.test(inputstring);

// now result contains true or false
```

Comment: You might consider `var pattern = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}-1/;`. Kudos for using *test* though. :-)

Comment: thank you very much I managed to successfully impliment the regexp method you suggested. I had to change the format to suit the format of the card no for anyone who needs to know: [a-zA-Z]{3}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1}

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have:

```
> var fourthp = pieces[2].slice(-1);
```

then it is pretty much guaranteed that it's a string, so when will

```
> (fourthp.length == 1 && typeof fourthp == "number")
```

ever be true? Even if it's a Number, then *fourthp.length* will be *undefined*, so it will always be false either way.